# jQuery - "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue when posting data through an AJAX call. My call is ending with below error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Wc (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

It seems this call doesn't hit the server. It's erroring out before getting there. Input values coming from textarea for fields `db_table_changes`, `db_column_changes`, `db_index_changes`, `db_queryplan_changes`, `db_stored_proc`.

JQuery Function:

```
 jQuery(function() {
    $('button.dbsubmit_btn').click(function(event){
        var relsdbid = $("#rels_db_id").val().trim();
        var dbTableChange = $("#db_table_changes").val().trim();
        var dbColumnChange = $("#db_column_changes").val().trim();
        var dbIndexChange = $("#db_index_changes").val().trim();
        var dbqueryplanchanges = $("#db_queryplan_changes").val().trim();
        var dbstoredproc = $("#db_stored_proc").val().trim();
        var dbpatch = $("#db_patch").val().trim();
        var dbreplication = $("#db_replication").val().trim();
        var dbothers = $("#db_others").val().trim();

// Field Validation comes here

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "./insert_db_property",
            data : {
                'rels_id' : release_id,
                'rels_db_id' : relsdbid,
                'db_table_changes' : dbTableChange,
                'db_column_changes' : dbColumnChange,
                'db_index_changes' : dbIndexChange,
                'db_queryplan_changes' : db_queryplan_changes,
                'db_stored_proc' : dbstoredproc,
                'db_patch' : dbpatch,
                'db_replication' : dbreplication,
                'db_others' : dbothers,
            },
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('RElease Revsion ' + data.index_changes);
                // $("svn_revision").val(data.release_revision_no);

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Button Definition:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
           <button type="submit" class="dbsubmit_btn btn btn-primary" 
                id="dbsubmit_btn" name="dbsubmit_btn" >
                     Save DBInfo<i class="fa fa-chevron-center"></i>
           </button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Sample TextArea Bootstrap Definition:

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" cols=""
      name="db_table_changes" id="db_table_changes"> 
           ${db_info.table_changes}
 </textarea>
```

Comment: Looks like there is a lot of code missing to understand what is going on and what might be going wrong. Could try reduce the problem first, maybe extract some parts of your code and for trying independently. In this excerpt there seems to be no code eligible for causing infinite recursion which seems to be the issue according to your error message. Note, that this error isn't pointing to the code causing the issue for running some probably complex code over and over again and clashing in a certain point because of running out of resources. Find the code causing to rerun whatever action it is.

Comment: Your data object is also invalid. There should be no comma on the last property.

Comment: Adriani6 I have corrected my data without comma.

Comment: @cepharum  you are right, my other part of the code caused this trouble. though I couldn't locate the infinite loop code, I corrected the partition issue in code. that resolved my issue. Thanks and appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Adriani6 Using additional comma after last property in a literal object definition isn't invalid (anymore). You've been discouraged from using it when some browsers in use were picky about it (such as MSIE 6 and Safari 5) while other browser were totally fine with that. But with ES5 this has become valid by definition eventually. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5 ... the pros and cons of using trailing comma are subject to biased discussions, though, e.g. teaching yourself to omit it to prevent accidental errors in writing JSON vs. simplifying addition of props.